# Sliding the table contents using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I need some help in sliding the table contents one row up/down, a column (left/right). So assume that the table has 10 rows but I can display on 4 at a time. Also the table has 10 columns and i can display just 5 at a time. Now I need to scroll rows/columns. Any help is appreciated.

I tried hiding a row/column, but in order to move a row, I need to get the id of the first visible row and the id of the last visible row. Thats where I am currently stuck. is there a way to find the Id of the first visible row/column. Also the Id of the last visible row/column. That would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to go by IDs. Start by storing everything relevant in variables: the constraints, but more importantly the currently visible row/col ID - or index rather, then increase/decrease that upon moving rows/cols.

Something along the lines of:

```
(function () {
    var $rows = $('.my-row'),
        numberOfRows = $rows.length,
        // assuming there is no colspan magic at work
        numberOfCols = $rows.children().first().length, 

        visibleRows = 4,
        visibleCols = 5,

        firstVisibleRow = 0, // not 1 because Arrays are 0-indexed
        firstVisibleCol = 0,

       moveDown = function () {
           $rows.slice(firstVisibleRow, numberOfRows).hide();
           firstVisibleRow += visibleRows;
           $rows.slice(firstVisibleRow, numberOfRows).show();
       },

       moveRight = function () {
           var newFirstVisibleCol = firstVisibleCol + visibleCols,
               i, len,
               currentRow;

           for (i = 0, len = $rows.length; i < len; i++) {
               currentRow = $rows.eq(i).children(); // TDs of current Row
               currentRow.slice(firstVisibleCol, visibleCols).hide();
               currentRow.slice(newFirstVisibleCol, visibleCols).show();
           }

           firstVisibleCol = newVisibleCol;
       },

       moveUp = function () {
           // ...
       }

       moveLeft = function () {
           // ...
       };


    // initialise the table, hide rows/cols 6 and on
    // bind events
    // etc
    // ...
}());
```

Once you have that, don't forget to add logic to take care of your numberOfRows/numberOfCols so you can't "scroll" past the bounds of the table.

---

In response to the comment below - since I can't use code tags in comments:

You can, for instance, use a

```
<buttonid="makeitMoveRight">Move 5 cols to the right</button>
```

then use

```
$("#makeItMoveRight").click(moveRight); // or
$("#makeItMoveRight").bind("click", moveRight) // which essentially do the same
```

within the closure (the outer function) above. You may want|have to add an extra parameter to the function expression, like

```
// add a parameter for the event passed by jQuery
moveRight = function (event) {
    // ... rest of the function here ...

    // also, add this:
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

to prevent default behaviour (such as submitting a surrounding form or follow a link/jumping to the top) if your control element is an anchor or a button for example.

Comment: I am new to JQuery, so hence the question. How do I tie a customer event to a control (like the table control in my case)? Will something like $("table").bind("moveDown", function(){  work?

Comment: Can't use <code> tags in comments it seems. See the edit to my answer instead.

Comment: is there an email that I could email you my code snippet at. I can't paste the code here as it does not allow me to paste the code in this box (requires some kind of fomrmatting).

Comment: any reason why it works in IE 8 but does not work in FF 9 or Chrome